# (g)Vim 7.x :: Possible to trick Vim into allowing lower-case user-defined commands

Tags: function, vim, naming-conventions

Not that it is seriously burdensome to type

```
:My_custom_foobar()
```

instead of just

```
:my_custom_foobar()
```

but it just feels odd considering how virtually every other aspect of Vim is so extensible. Some searching for an answer has not turned up much, but I know it's got to be possible without having to recompile Vim from source. Does anyone out there know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: The vimdoc says the reason for this is so there won't be many collisions between user defined and built-in functions. built-in ones have lower case letters starting out (except for 3 of them), so there's no confusion. It seems like this is a purposeful restriction then.

Comment: Maybe start out all functions with P or L? Right next to colon, and you're going to be hitting shift for that anyways. Very inelegant though.

Comment: Yeah, I know there is a legit rationale behind it, I am just not a big fan of that particular design decision (languages and applications that use letter-case as hack for namespace collision avoidance). I'm sure *someone* out there has wanted to change this besides just me.

Comment: Who cares about functions conflicting? let me shoot myself in the foot... The only other language I can think of that doesn't let you redefine functions is PHP >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try [mapping](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_3)).

```
nnoremap <Leader>f :call My_custom_foobar()<CR>
```

You have to do it one function at a time.  Not sure how you would go about doing it for all functions.  I say stick to convention and type the capital letter for function name.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with a :abbrev, but it's really not recommended. The reason you cannot do this is because of: 1) vi compatibility, 2) future expansion.

Point 2 is the bigger issue -- if you could write functions, then there's no guarantee that you don't wind up naming one that later conflicts with a built-in function, and this is simply not allowed. You'd end up getting errors when trying to load the function.